# Blur filter in assembler

Tags: assembly, filter, blur

I am trying to get it working but still no results. Do you know some kind of tutorial or sample assembler code for blur image filtering?

Comment: you probably need to specify the instruction set.
But is there a particular reason to do it in assembly?

Comment: You should probably post the code and explain what the problem is, i.e. why it "doesn't work"

Comment: You should probably be thinking about the problem on a higher level. Once you have an idea of the general algorithm you want to use for blurring the image, it's "just" a matter of expressing that algorithm in assembly.

Comment: Which kind of blur? The easiest and fastest would be a simple average, but others such as Gaussian might be more appropriate for your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could blur with a [convolution matrix](http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-convmatrix.html).

Depending about the system, you can use the older floating point stuff, integer arithmetic or newer SSE ops.

If you are using a byte to represent color value, here's an overall algorithm:

```
calculate sum of convolution matrix (in blur matrix that would be 9)
Clear destination register
load each byte under convolution matrix
multiply each byte with its corresponding number in the convolution matrix
place the sum into the destination register
divide destination register with the sum of convolution matrix
store the destination register into destination buffer
```